# enumitem counter scope issue

Tags: enumitem, mdframed

An mdframe blocks global counting. How can I resolve this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This should have a numeral of one.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{mdframed}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item This should have a numeral of two.
\end{enumerate}

\end{mdframed}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item This should have a numeral of three.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see the documentation. Below resume it says "This is done locally. If you want global resuming, see next section on series."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this kind of global resume, it's best to use the `series` key for the list and then use `resume=...` to resume it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[series=mylist]
\item This should have a numeral of one.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{mdframed}

\begin{enumerate}[resume=mylist]
\item This should have a numeral of two.
\end{enumerate}

\end{mdframed}

\begin{enumerate}[resume=mylist]
\item This should have a numeral of three.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]